# What is RLMCollection replacement in RealmSwift

Tags: swift, realm

```
var objects:RLMCollection!

if selectedObject != nil {
            objects = selectedObject.childobjects as RLMArray
        } else {
            objects = RealmObject.objectsInRealm(realm, "isFavourite == 1")
        }

println(couplets.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! RealmObject)
```

I had a senario, where I won't know whether I need to work with RLMArray or RLMResults, so I used RLMCollection.

How can I achieve the same in RealmSwift 0.93.1

Answer (score 0):

In general, in Swift it's good enough to work with a `CollectionType`, which defines subscripting, enumeration, and many of the other 'array-like' methods that `Results` and `List` expose. (Though we are interested in adding a `RealmCollectionType` protocol, just haven't gotten around to it yet!)